# Using <compc> to build SWC

Tags: actionscript-3, ant, air, flash-builder, swc

I am using ant to build swc automatically, but the built swc only 3K. I checked several solutions, but there is nothing difference with my build.xml, Help!

my build.xml looks like as following

```
<compc debug="true" output="${OUTPUT_DIR}\ExternalLib.swc">
    <source-path path-element="${SOURCE_DIR}" />
    <include-sources dir="${SOURCE_DIR}" includes="*" />
    <external-library-path file="${AIR_SDK_HOME}\frameworks\libs\air\airglobal.swc" append=true />
</compc>
```

Note: I unpacked swc and checked catalog.xml. No classes included. I don't know why.
My source directory structure is

```
src
    --PNGEncoder.as
    --Box2D
    ----Collision
    ------[Kinds of AS files]
    ----Common
    ------[Kinds of AS files]
    ----Dynamics
    ------[Kinds of AS files]
    --deng
    ----fzip
    ------[Kinds of AS files]
    ----utils
    ------[Kinds of AS files]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try update config as:

```
<compc debug="true" output="${OUTPUT_DIR}/ExternalLib.swc">
    <source-path path-element="${SOURCE_DIR}/"/>
    <include-sources dir="${SOURCE_DIR}/" includes="*" />

    <include-libraries dir='${AIR_SDK_HOME}/frameworks/libs/air/' append='true'>
        <include name="airglobal.swc" />
    </include-libraries>
</compc>
```